# Show that the PDF is valid

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $F$ be the CDF of a continuous r.v., and $f = F'$ be the PDF.
Show that g defined by $g(x)=2F(x)f(x)$ is also a valid PDF

Since, $f(x)$ is a valid PDF=> $F(x)$ is non-decreasing=> $g(x)>=0$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \ dx =2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x)f(x) \ dx = 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dxf(x) \ dx =2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx=2$$

What is wrong here?

Comment: you have to use dummy indices for the cdf. you are probably confusing the integrals.

Comment: Just one supplement: $g$ is the pdf of the maximum of two i.i.d. random variables with common CDF $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we substitute $u = F(x)$, $du = f(x) \, dx$, we get $$2 \int_{x=-\infty}^\infty F(x) f(x) \, dx = 2 \int_{u = 0}^1 u \, du = 2 \left[\frac{u^2}{2}\right]_{u=0}^1 = 1.$$  The change of the limits of integration occurs because $$\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x) = 0, \quad \lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$$ for any CDF of a real-valued random variable.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x)f(x) \, dx =2\int_{0}^{1} t\, dt=2(1/2)=1
$$
where we made the change of variables $t=F(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up with the integrals.

$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt$ by definition, so   $f(x)=F'(x)$

So:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2F(x)F'(x)dx = [F^{2}(x)]_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 1$

Where the last passage is an improper integral and you have to know that:

$\lim_{x->-\infty}F(x) = 0$

$\lim_{x->+\infty}F(x) = 1$